# Full screen mode in php

Tags: php

I developed online exam for education company.I want to make my exam open on full screen mode.I tried several codes but don't work.Any help?
I disabled right click and f12.

Comment: PHP runs on the server side and doesn't know anything about a "screen". You need client side code for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Javascript.
You can add a button or link that calls goFS() in it's href to trigger fullscreen in browser.

```
<script>
function goFS(){
        if (fs.requestFullscreen) {
            fs.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (fs.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            fs.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (fs.msRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
</script>
```